# How to use multi conditions with a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use three conditions inside a ternary operator?

Or is there any better idea rather than legacy if conditions to achieve this?

```js
let tmpgender = $('#gender').text().trim();
let gender = null;
tmpgender == "female" ? gender : 'f';
tmpgender == "male" ? gender : 'm';
tmpgender == "unisex" ? gender : 'u';

console.log(gender);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">female</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use an object indexed by `tmpgender` instead:

```js
const genders = {
  female: 'f',
  male: 'm',
  unisex: 'u'
};
const tmpgender = $('#gender').text().trim();
const gender = genders[tmpgender];
console.log(gender);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">female</div>
```

If you *had* to use the conditional operator, you could do

```js
const genders = {
  female: 'f',
  male: 'm',
  unisex: 'u'
};
const tmpgender = $('#gender').text().trim();
const gender = tmpgender === 'female'
  ? 'f'
  : tmpgender === 'male'
    ? 'm'
    : tmpgender === 'unisex'
      ? 'u'
      : 'unknown';
console.log(gender);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">female</div>
```

But that's ugly and hard to read, I strongly prefer the object method.

Answer (score 2):

Try Following

```js
let tmpgender = $('#gender').text().trim();
let gender = tmpgender == "female" ? 'f' : tmpgender == "male" ? 'm' : 'u';

console.log(gender);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gender">female</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... In your case no need for ternary

```js
const tmpgender = "male";
let gender = tmpgender.charAt(0);
console.log(gender);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mplungjan provided a good answer but still If you want to check multiple conditions with Ternary operator, then here is an option:

```
<script>
    var tmpgender = $('#gender').text().trim();
    var gender = null;

    gender = tmpgender == "female" ? 'f': tmpgender == "male" ? 'm' : tmpgender == "unisex" ? 'u' : null;

</script>
```

I would suggest to use simpler methods like fetching first letter.